# Unable to Initialize Vector for C++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, vector, c++17

When I am running the following lines of code to initialize a vector, test score with integers I am getting an error. Please help me find what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector <int> test_scores {100, 98, 91, 84, 78, 75, 71}; 

    return 0;
}
```

here is the error I am getting:

```
Anishs-MacBook-Air:C++ anishnagariya$ cd "/Users/anishnagariya/Desktop/C++/" && g++ vectors.cpp -o vectors && "/Users/anishnagariya/Desktop/C++/"vectors
vectors.cpp:8:29: error: expected ';' at end of declaration
    vector <int> test_scores {100, 98, 91, 84, 78, 75, 71}; 
                            ^
                            ;
1 error generated.
Anishs-MacBook-Air: C++ anishnagariya$
```

Comment: Try adding `-std=c++2a` to `g++` command. And renaming file to `.cpp` extension.

Comment: Maybe insert  `=` ?

Comment: @Arty c++17 should be more than sufficient to  enable this syntax. Either OP tagged that question wrongly, or its a feature missing from their particular compiler.

Comment: _@AnishNagariya_ Would you be so kind and please tell us, what's the exact gcc version you're using? You can easily obtain that using the code like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b470c91b1299cea3). As you tagged this question with the [tag:c++17] tag, I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/102ae10e239c1cb2) what you claim.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it is not reproducible because on later versions of GCC `-std=c++11` is used by default, which is enough for this syntax. Probably OP has some very old compiler version.

Comment: @Arty That's why I asked the OP for their precise compiler version. If that already can acknowlege the `-std=c++11` flag, your answer solves the problem, if not the OP needs to update their compiler.

Comment: If someone is using code runner extension, follow the following steps.
Step 1 Goto > Code > Preferences > Settings
Step 2 Search for code runner
Step 3 Click settings.json file and replace "cpp" with the following LOC
`"cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -std=c++11 -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `-std=c++11` to your `g++` command, your syntax is only valid from C++11 standard and that should be stated to your compiler.

Flag `-std=c++11` should be provided to only quite old GCC compiler, more recent versions use this flag by default. So another way to solve your task and not to include any flags is to upgrade your compiler. You may figure out your version of GCC by [this code](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCVVwSYzv7ikKDUx146LKzOvRCE3MTNPQ1OhmksBCIpLUqyskvNLSxRsbBTi48Ncg4I9/f3i40FcsFxqXkqONVft//8A).

Also if rest of your code is C++17-based then you may use flag `-std=c++17`.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/8P9h4j).